# Change color of part of the string between backslashes

Tags: excel, vba

I am stuck with this problem: I would like to loop in all the worksheets of a woorkbook performing this specific action: changing the color to  the part of a string between the last backslashes, in the Organisation column:

This is the original data 
[image]

This is how I would like to change the string as follow:
[image]

The part of the string that I would like to change color doesn't have the same lenght (otherwise I could solve the issue with the Right function). Do you have any suggestion how I can code a subroutine to solve that?

Comment: Could you share the code you wrote to solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manipulate the properties of a substring within a cell's string value, you need to use the Range.Characters property. This requires a starting point and a length to identify the substring.

Since you want the positions of the trailing backslashes, using InStrRev would likely be more efficient than InStr in determining these positions.

```
Sub redBetweenBackslashes()

    Dim i As Long, s As Long, e As Long, str As String

    With Worksheets("sheet4")
        For i = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            str = .Cells(i, "A").Value2
            e = InStrRev(str, Chr(92), -1, vbBinaryCompare) - 1
            If e > 0 Then
                s = InStrRev(str, Chr(92), e, vbBinaryCompare) + 1
                If s > 1 Then
                    With .Cells(i, "A").Characters(Start:=s, Length:=e - s + 1)
                        .Font.Color = vbRed
                        .Font.Bold = True
                    End With
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

I've added Bold formatting to the red font color.

[image]

Comment: Hello @user10829321 , your proposed solution works pretty good, except the fact that it changes only to strings in column A. Any clue how to apply this solution to all worksheet, where the title of the cell is "Orgnisation", I have more than one cell with the same name. Many thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

You need something like the above using instrrev

```
Function MarkRed()
Dim R As Long
For R = 28 To 29 ' just a sample
    MarkTextRed (Cells(R, 2))
Next
End Function

Public Function MarkTextRed(myCell As Range)
Dim T As String
Dim b As Integer, c As Integer
T = myCell.Value
b = InStrRev(T, "\")
c = InStrRev(T, "\", b - 1)
If c < b Then
    With myCell.Characters(Start:=c + 1, Length:=(b - c - 1)).Font
        .Color = -16776961
    End With
End If
End Function
```